# Hosting digital asset link json file in a path instead of domain root?

Tags: security, android-7.0-nougat, android-deep-link, fido, digital-assets-links

Has anyone tried hosting **assetlinks.json** file in a query path instead of domain root?

**Background:**
We are currently working on Android FIDO Client implementation which interacts with custom FIDO server application.

Here is the codelab if you're interested to play around with Android FIDO2
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/fido2-for-android/#2

**Problem:** 
If we host the file in some other location(aka query path), Google Fido2ApiClient throws an error.

> SECURITY_ERR(18) : The incoming request cannot be validated

According to Google Digital Links [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#publish-json), they recommend assetlinks.json file to be hosted in domain root.

> https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json

For security reasons, our SecOps team is not OK with the idea. 
So my ask to you is : Can we host this assetlinks.json file in a path like below?

> https://domain.name/application/v1/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Advance thanks for your comments!

Comment: Given this is the same path that letsecrypt uses, you might want to push back on the secops team.